# How to account for special characters \% in mapping

Tags: key-bindings, external-command, microsoft-windows

I am using vim on Windows and have following mappings:

```
imap <f4> <ESC>:w<CR>:!clang -std=c++11 -o output\%.exe %<CR>
imap <f5> <ESC>:!output\%.exe<CR>
```

As we know in windows `\` is path separator `\` also used in escape sequences in vim-script and commands this command gives me out put as sown in pic.
[image: output I am getting]
What I want is shown in the following pic
[image]

My intention is to compile the source and return the output in the 'output' directory  and execute from there.

Instead, I get 'output%' as output in the current directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should always use `inoremap` rather than `imap` (with a small number of exceptions that are not relevant here).

The difficulty here is that as soon as `%` is put after `\`, the backslash goes from path component to escaping character. The only way I could prevent that is to use an expression (`<expr>` on lhs of the mapping) so I could use `expand("%")` in it:

```
inoremap <expr> <f4> '<ESC>:w<CR><ESC>:!clang -std=c++11 -o output\' . expand("%") . '.exe ' . expand("%") . '<CR>'
inoremap <expr> <f5> '<ESC>:!output\' . expand("%") . '.exe<CR>'
```

**Update :** Actually I found a way to do this without `<expr>`. The second "Note" under `:help E809` says that double quotes can be used to isolate `%` while retaining its special meaning. It looks a little strange on the `cmd.exe` command line but it works in my tests.

```
inoremap <f4> <ESC>:w<CR><ESC>:!clang -std=c++11 -o output\"%".exe %<CR>
inoremap <f5> <ESC>:!output\"%".exe<CR>
```

Comment: @B Layer   
my question was poorly worded. let me elaborate more clearly. I have a directory ` code` for source files for example a.cpp which will be value for expand("%:r") or % . I have a directory inside code called output I want output executable in this output directory. ` output%.exe  expands to outputa.CPP.exe inside code directory. what I want is a.CPP.exe inside code\output

Comment: @mage Please edit your question and add the extra information. Include clear example of input and output filenames/directories. Also, pay close attention to what you write.  "vim on window" isn't very clear. "vim on Windows" is.

Comment: @B Layer  Windows  has `\` for path separator which is used in vim for escape sequences.

Comment: @mage The edit was a big improvement but you fundamentally changed at least one thing: going from `nmap` to `imap`. That kinda messes my answer up. Anyways, I just appended a new solution until I get a chance to completely rewrite it. I tested this on Windows.

Comment: @mage Were you able to apply my new solution?

Comment: @mage Thanks for accepting my answer. As a bonus I found a cleaner way to do the mappings. ;)